# Python and Flask - Create temporary files from uploaded files for processing

Tags: python, flask

First a disclosure: I'm not a dev - just a hobbyist trying to make something work. Bear with me...!

I created a script that builds a Flask app. When launching the app, you can upload a Word document. The app converts the content from the Word doc into HTML code (using the Mammoth library), performs some operations to fix some attribute issues, and spits back the HTML page (and the code).

Locally, it works as intended. One downside is that if I want to try upload another word doc, I need to stop and restart the script. I think it's because of the way I'm saving the uploaded word doc.

The code for uploading the docx is:

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        filename = secure_filename(f.filename)
        f.save(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + filename)
        file = open(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + filename,"rb")
```

And the code to convert the docx to html is:

```
    with file as docx_file:
        result = mammoth.convert_to_html(docx_file, style_map = custom_styles)
        text = result.value
        with open('transitory/doc.html', 'w', encoding= 'unicode_escape') as html_file:
            html_file.write(text)
```

This works fine locally (though I have to manually purge the upload folder once in a while, and I need to restart the script to convert a different file).

I tried to deploy the script to Heroku, using instructions from https://dev.to/lordofdexterity/deploying-flask-app-on-heroku-using-github-50nh. When using the Heroku app, the Flask app launches as intended. But when I try to upload a file, it breaks, and the following error message is in the logs:

```
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492828+00:00 app[web.1]:     rv = self.dispatch_request()
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492829+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492829+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492829+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/app.py", line 38, in html_convert
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492830+00:00 app[web.1]:     f.save(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] + filename)
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492830+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/werkzeug/datastructures.py", line 3021, in save
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492831+00:00 app[web.1]:     dst = open(dst, "wb")
2022-02-02T19:46:34.492831+00:00 app[web.1]: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'upload/simple_formatting.docx'
2022-02-02T19:46:34.493449+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.1.89.26 - - [02/Feb/2022:19:46:34 +0000] "POST /html_convert HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://doc-to-html.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/97.0.4692.71 Safari/537.36 Edg/97.0.1072.55"
2022-02-02T19:46:34.496937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/html_convert" host=doc-to-html.herokuapp.com request_id=409b6153-bac9-4251-8f81-c3307f5cf920 fwd="198.103.221.52" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=191ms status=500 bytes=463 protocol=https
```

Is there a way for the uploaded docx file to not be saved at all in a folder? To have it as a temporary file that gets deleted once the HTML file is created? Would that work on a Heroky deployment?

I'm guessing I'd want to do the same thing with the HTML file that gets created:

- upload the docx file as a temporary file
- convert the temporary docx into a temporary HTML file
- show the created HTML file in a template

The whole code of the Flask app is here: https://github.com/quidampepin/doc_to_html/blob/main/app.py

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer:
By switching the upload folder name to /tmp, it works.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).